# Ajax post:Not able to retrieve posted data in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to post a data using ajax call. The ajax call us working fine but when I am alerting the data, it is showing all the html tags and then I am not able to retrieve the data in php.

My code for file Filterpage.php is as below:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
  $data= $_POST['grpNm'];
  echo $data;
?>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var GrpNm="ABC";
   $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url:"FilterPage.php",
         data: {grpNm : GrpNm},
         success: function(data){ 
             alert(data);
                  },
                  
          error:function(data){ 
              alert("No"); 
                  },
                  
                });
         
      });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The alert(data) in ajax call is giving all the html tags and in php I am getting the following error:
Notice: undefined index:grpNm

Please help me where I am doing wrong.. I have searched many questions and tried the answers but not working

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST)` and make sure it is what you expect. Error says what you expect is not there.

Comment: It is giving NULL .why is it so when I am posting the data

Comment: Use browser developer console, what does it show for the "Ajax" post? Did it succeed? Inspect the values sent. Is the string of HTML data being returned and shown by that alert containing any error message?

Comment: I am getting status:200, statusText:OK

Comment: Also I got : exception:typeerror:caller,calle and arguments properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments at function.r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you miss something. Your Ajax call didn't return `undefined index:grpNm` when you open the file in browser `localhost/Filterpage.php` PHP can't find `$_POST['grpNm']` then your ajax fires and request to the same file.

As you return HTML as well it's obvious you see some HTML too. you should kill the process after `echo $data;` so the rest of the page will not return in the output.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['grpNm'])){
    echo $_POST['grpNm'];
    
    die;
  }
  
?>
<html>
<body>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var GrpNm="ABC";
   $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url:"Filterpage.php",
         data: {grpNm : GrpNm},
         success: function(data){ 
             alert(data);
         },
                  
          error:function(data){ 
              alert("No"); 
          },
                  
       });
         
   });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So here you echo data at the top and kill the process after that. then no HTML will return to ajax call. we also check if the index exists that prevents `undefined index:grpNm` warning when you open the URL.

also, it's a good idea to separate your business logic to another PHP file and call that PHP file via ajax.

Comment: The ajax call us successful but then why I am not able to retrieve the data in php.. it is showing NULL when I am using var_dump($_POST['grpNm']

Comment: Also I have tried putting the logic in another php file, still it is showing NULL but when I am alerting the data in ajax success call, it is showing the correct data

Comment: did you test the code I just post? and you still get null in the alert?

Comment: Yes I tried and nothing is coming, not even NULL when I am using var_dump

Comment: Try to put `var_dump($_POST)` or `var_dump($_REQUEST)` instead of `if` block in my code above. remove the `if` block and put one of the `var_dump` and come back to me with the output

Comment: The alert shows array(1) {['grpNm']}=> string(3) "ABC"  but the same thing when I am doing echo in php is showing array(0){}

Comment: Ok, the alert is important for us; because it uses the Post method. which one did you test? `var_dump($_POST)` or `var_dump($_REQUEST)`

Comment: I tested Both and the results are same null array

Comment: `The alert shows array(1) {['grpNm']}=> string(3) "ABC"` ? so when did you get that?

Comment: Everytime alert is displaying the data but I am not able to retrieve the data in php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242299/discussion-between-sajjad-rezaei-and-uddipana).